# Silly question about factors. What does it mean to reduce a number by a factor of 10 or 5 and so on?

Tags: factoring, machine-learning

I am currently doing a Deep Learning project, and I am trying to decrease my learning rate by a factor of 5.

If my Learning Rate is 0.0004, then would 0.0004 * 0.05 decrease it by a factor of 5? My dyslexic brain and poor English language does not let me understand this.

My model has an initial Learning Rate which is 0.0004. I want to reduce it by a factor of **N** if the accuracy of the model does not increase after a set amount of epochs. Is it division or multiplication?

Just for reference, I am trying to implement [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ReduceLROnPlateau) in my project.
The factor parameter says:

> factor: factor by which the learning rate will be reduced. new_lr = lr * factor.

Sorry if this is a truly silly question, but I am stuck! Thank you :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To "decrease something by a factor of $N$" means "divide it by $N$". If you decrease $100$ by a factor of $5$ you get $20$, for example. This is the same as "multiply it with $\frac{1}{N}$. In the previous example, "decrease by a factor of $5$" also means "multiply by $\frac{1}{5}$", or "multiply by $0.2$".

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you, can you post it below so I can mark it as an answer? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reduce a quantity, $q$, by a factor of $n$, simply divide by $n$.

$\text{Reduced factor} = q * n^{-1} = q / n$